# In table view I want to add a view its height should be dynamic according to cell height

Tags: ios, objective-c

In `UITableview` I am adding another `UIView`, it's height should be dynamic according to cell height, the problem I am facing is it is not accurate.
The height of `UIView` is not varying correctly with cell and it is calculated again and again on table reloading.

Comment: Pls post the code how you are doing this?

Comment: cell in multiple record or single record?

Comment: can you tell me that you create coustom tableview cell or you want to add view programmetically in cell?

Comment: Created Custom table cell

Answer (score 0):

When you load your data, you can calculate the each cell's height, and store them in a array, then you can use this frame array to setup the uiview's frame

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide constraints on your `UIView` according to `contentView` of cell top,bottom,leading,trailing value 0 , So your UIView height and width is same as cell height & width.

Please refer http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1 for learning autoLayout for beginner.